# Angular 4 - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 for POST, PUT method

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, preflight

During the testing in local environment, I encountered HTTP error 403.

In my Angular service files, I have the headers set as following:

```
const apiArgs: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
apiArgs.headers = headers;
```

And one example of POST call that I made

```
 return this.http.post(environment.urlPath, JSON.stringify(output), apiArgs)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

What needs to be configured?

Comment: Looks like issue is from server not from angular side

Comment: Yes the issue is coming from server side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem with you.
you could make it clear that you 403 request is a options request and not your origin post request.because your post request with the "content-type" header is not a "simple request".It will send a preflight request.
403 means your request is forbidden.are you forget some credential information?

I figure it out by the proxy.